# Ionic BLE central startNotification not firing custom callbacks

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, capacitor

I'm trying to build a Capacitor App, that communicates with a Bluno Beetle BLE Microcontroller. I'm using the Ionic/Cordova BLE Central plugin. The Beetle writes a (different) message every second, that I can recieve via "Listen for Notification" in the LightBlue App (Bluetooth testing App). In my App I'm trying to replicate this by using the following code (after successfully connecting and being able to read data):

```
  this.ble.startNotification(beetle, beetle_service_UUID, beetle_characteristics_UUID)
  .subscribe(
        data => console.log("on data"),
        error => console.log("on error")
  );
```

When I run the iOS-App via XCode after pushing the "Subscribe" button I get notifications in the console saying

> 2021-06-22 10:38:54.223765+0200 App[66723:4263573] didUpdateValueForCharacteristic

However my own callback (console.log("on data")) is not being displayed.

In my understanding this shows, that receiving the notifications works and fires up an event, but my custom callback is somehow ignored. Does someone see the mistake made in here or knows where it could come from? I'm starting to get a bit desperate as there is no error firing and no possibility to debug.

Comment: Could you try declaring a onData and onError function and passing them to `startNotification` as described here https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#quick-example-7 and in this full example https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central/blob/master/examples/heartrate/www/js/index.js#L61

Comment: When I pass the onData and onError to startNotification directly, I get an error message saying there were 3 arguments expected but 5 given.

Comment: oh I see... Could you try `this.ble.startNotification(beetle, beetle_service_UUID, beetle_characteristics_UUID)
  .subscribe(buffer => {
   *   console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));`

Comment: I tried but the * fires an error (expression expected) and without it it's the same story as before.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue -- and it took me a lot of time to resolve because I was looking in the wrong place.  For me, the source of the problem was on the BLE server and not on the ionic app (although I fault Ionic/Angular/Cordova BLE for the lack of error messages).  To resolve the issue, I added a 2902 descriptor to the characteristic in my ESP32 server.  This is in addition to setting the notification flag on the characteristic:

```
#include <BLE2902.h>

pService->addCharacteristic(&statusCharacteristic);
BLE2902* p2902Descriptor = new BLE2902();
p2902Descriptor->setNotifications(true);
statusCharacteristic.addDescriptor(p2902Descriptor);
```